# Make CSS hover element permanent onclick

Tags: javascript, css

So I have created a little box with some CSS animation:

```
.boxtest 
{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
opacity: .2;
transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity .8s, width.8s ease-out;
}

.boxtest:hover {
opacity: 1;
width: 70%;
}
```

What I'd like is for the CSS hover class to remain permanent after the user has hovered their mouse over the element.

I guess you'd need to use Javascript, but I'm no expert so can't figure out the right command.  Any help would be awesome!

http://jsfiddle.net/r75gC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

Basically I used jQuery to add a class to the `div`. You can choose one of the two below.

```
//onClick
$(".boxtest").on("click", function () {
  $(".boxtest").addClass('permahover');
});

//onHover
$(".boxtest").on("mouseenter", function () {
  $(".boxtest").addClass('permahover');
});
```

I changed the CSS to:

```
.boxtest:hover,
.permahover {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 70%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rFRc5/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't a lot of experience with javascript I would recommend using JQuery. Use this to include the JQuery libraries in your website:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

this will allow you to simply do (in your html file):

```
<script> 
$(".boxtest").mouseenter(function() { $(".boxtest").addClass("boxtestHover"); });
</script>
```

also for the above change .boxtest:hover to boxtesthover (or whatever you want)

Comment: Sorry this still doesn't seem to work - I have added your suggestion to http://jsfiddle.net/vXuCA/1/ but it doesn't stay after the user hovers/click.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your css file you have change boxtest:hover to something else, in my code i have changed it to boxtestHover (probably should've made that clearer haha)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a bit overkill for this.

Instead of hover, use another class name, then just add this to the element

```
onmouseover="this.className='newClassName'"
```